# How to catch string in txt file using scanner?

Tags: java, string, hyperlink, text-files, java.util.scanner

I'm using this sample code to make one search through one text file:

```
private void buildLink(){

           int wordCount = 0, totalcount = 0;
           Scanner s = new Scanner(googleNode);
           while (s.hasNext()) {
               totalcount++;

            if (s.next().equals("href")) wordCount++;
           }
           System.out.println(wordCount+" "+totalcount);
       }
```

but my problem is s.hasNext is jumping most of the words on the search (maybe cos the text file is one html code and almost has none space characters). For this sample code the output count is:

wordCount = 0
totalCount = 18056

So, what exactly Im doing wrong and what should I do to resolve in an alternative away since what I want is to catch one link inside this html code and pass to a String variable?

One way I thought to do this was to put the entire html code in one string and then treat the search, but this is too damn ridiculous as a good programmer..

Could anybody help me please? thanks in advance

Comment: With equals you find the exactly word "href" in each line, perhaps search if the line contains the string href.

Comment: For a file like `<a href="b">c</a>`, Scanner see `<a` and `href="b">c</a>` by default.

Comment: if (s.next().contains("href")) wordCount++; } System.out.println(wordCount+" "+totalcount); }  i think that with this is must work.

Comment: @johnchen902 that is what I was thinking, and thats the reason its jumping the words, so what should I do? any ideas?

Comment: @Deckard27 damn u man, thank you very much! its working =))) post as an answer therefore I can accept ur contribuition please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (s.next().contains("href")) wordCount++; } System.out.println  (wordCount+" "+totalcount); }
```

i think that with this is must work

Comment: Maybe you can change `"href"` to `" href="`, in order to reduce false positives.

Comment: @johnchen902 is a good idea but he also can search "<a href=" the problem is that with equals you search the exactly string